# how to get started making games with java

Tags: java

I was wondering how could I get started making games with java? I tried looking up tutorials but I couldnt find any ,also if I make a game with java and it connects to a database would someone be able to decompile the game and see the stuff to connect to the database

Comment: Maybe you can share with us how much Java programming you've done (like how comfortable you are with it), and what kind of game you have in mind -- or what specifically you want to learn. 2D? 3D?

Comment: Connecting directly from a client to a remote database on your own server is just asking for trouble.  Use an go-between service to accept requests, which then makes sure the request is valid and then return the results.

Comment: I really recommend you start with something simpler, like the answer below about Space Invaders. Or even pong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/), and it's documentation (teaches you the basic stuff). [Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net) uses the same library.

Answer (score 2):

Looooong time ago, when I was trying to start programming with Java, I followed a tutorial to create a simple Space Invaders in Java. I am pretty sure that there are much new (and better?) tutorials currently available on the net, but just in case... [**this**](http://www.plainview.k12.tx.us/Portals/0/docs/richard.desoto/resources/Back%20to%20Space%20Invaders%20Main.html) is the tutorial I followed. It has 27 lessons that you can follow, and at the end you end up with a nice Space Invaders :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in making a game and not building an engine you may want to look at [Java Monkey Engine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) and head straight to their tutorials [Tutorials](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3#tutorials_for_beginners)

You didn't mention how experienced you are at coding in Java but you will want to either look at tutorials in OpenGL for 3D work or research Tile engines for 2D.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LWJGL with Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/).